# There is a issue in parsing the package, android?

Tags: android, android-package-managers, android-parser

I've made this application, which I've been testing for a while now. 
When I was done I put it on the Market store and it was all good but now a made a new version, not changing the manifest it gives me an error on my phone when I try to install it:

There is a problem parsing the package.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

I had no problems with the app before but why now?

Comment: Did you update the versioncode and version name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error happened to me a couple of time and I was able to fix it by cleaning the project in Eclipse. Under Project / Clean

I sometimes have to clean and restart Eclipse after before building the package. Hope this help.