# Parsing apk file errors

Tags: android

I have a simple Tax Calculator App which i wanted to share via email.

I have created an APK file and emailed to my gmail.

The purpose was to test whether the app will install.

It has failed with the error "there is a problem parsing the package".

I am able to install this app(apk file) using adb tool on the phone it fails to install when downloaded from gmail.

Any reason(s) why the downloaded file failed? I have enable install from unknown sources in the device settings.

Ronald

Comment: works for me.  Do it all the time.

Comment: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1736822

Comment: How you created apk file? Means usign from bin folder or with signed apk?

Comment: Solution here worked:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923017/there-is-a-issue-parsing-the-package-android

Comment: check the SDK_VERSION in manifest file.. also how did you created apk?